# POI Name '_xlfn.IFNA' is completely unknown in the current workbook

Tags: java, excel

I have an Excel 2013 XLSM document that I am working with using POI 3.12.  This is an existing document that does some calculations and I am using POI to open it, imput data, then run the calculations.  The problem lies with the numerous fields that include functions like:

```
=IF('VEH1'!B10>3,SUM(H11:W11),0)
```

When I caclulate these cells I get an error:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Name '_xlfn.IFNA' is completely unknown in the current workbook
```

I am calculating using:

```
    XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells((XSSFWorkbook) book);
```

I also tried caclulating each Cell for a specific sheet, in case a sheet I wasn't using for that specific task had errors, but I get the same error for all cells that use =IF():

```
public void recalculateSheet(final String tabName) {
    final FormulaEvaluator eval = new XSSFFormulaEvaluator((XSSFWorkbook) book);
    final Sheet sheet = book.getSheet(tabName);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
        for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNum++) {
            final Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
            if (row != null) {
                for (int cellNum = 0; cellNum < row.getLastCellNum(); cellNum++) {
                    final Cell cell = row.getCell(cellNum);
                    if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                        try {
                            eval.clearAllCachedResultValues();
                            eval.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
                        } catch (final FormulaParseException e) {
                            logger.warn(tabName + " " + rowNum + "," + cellNum + ": " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                logger.debug("Sheet " + tabName + " does not have a row " + rowNum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As "IF" is a standard, built in function for Excel 2013, how can I resolve this error in POI?

Comment: The error is not about `IF` but about `IFNA` - https://support.office.com/en-us/Article/IFNA-function-6626c961-a569-42fc-a49d-79b4951fd461. And the prefix `_xlfn` shows that this function was not supported from the Excel version which has created the XLSM document. Sure, there are no `IFNA` formulas?

Comment: There may be some. But, if I eveluate cell by cell I get a list of errors like: `WARN  XLSStream - Tab: VEH1 Cell: 2,7 - Name '_xlfn.IFNA' is completely unknown in the current workbook.`  Looking at the workbook, I see the formula in row 2, column 7 (using Java counting starting at 0, of course) is: `=IF('VEH1'!B10>0,SUM(H11:W11),0)`  Is it remapping it internally to IFNA?

Comment: Maybe the `IFNA` is in `H11:W11` as the `SUM` has to be evaluated first before the `IF` can be evaluated.

Comment: Ah, so it does.  Well, kind of. H11 references H73 which references H35 which does have IFNA. So, now to figure out how to add support for IFNA to POI via the [tutorial](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html). Or see if I can replace the IFNA calls with plain IFs.

Comment: `=IFNA(A1,B1)` should be `=IFERROR(A1,IF(ISNA(A1),B1,A1))` as a nearly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "=IFERROR(A1,if(isna(A1),B1,A1)" 
And for entire row, it can be done like - 
IFERROR(E:E,IF(ISNA(E:E),F:F,E:E))

Answer (score 0):

This is issue is because of apache poi version. It occurs in poi version less than 5. Either you need to upgrade poi version to 5.x.x or just replace the IFNA function with other function like IFERROR